# -moz-border-radius removed from firefox 13

Tags: firefox, css

Yesterday I updated to firefox 13 and I notice that this property is not any more supported by firefox 13, jquery.ui.css make use of this, and now I have all jquery ui elements with no round corners. Any solution before replacing all manually in css file with border-radius?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you using a custom theme that doesn't use the standard property, or are the official themes the ones that miss it?

Comment: I am using several themes, some of version 1.7- 1.8.6 not custom, just downloaded from jquery site

Comment: It was about time to start using the standard! It is a principle to have same interface and different implementation.

Comment: I've just upgraded to Firefox 13 and [round corners in official themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) look fine :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario they look fine even without prefix! :-D

Comment: I have 1.8.6 Theme version official, maybe the last one is updated.

Comment: @albanx - I've just checked some sites that use old jQuery UI versions and I see rounded corners everywhere. I have the impression that your problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps you want to consider picking an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius

says it was removed in 13, theres no other option than to change it to border-radius. I wouldn't call it manual, open them in a text editor and do a search and replace

Comment: Yes I have 100 reference of this property for example **-moz-border-radius-topleft** is translated to **border-top-left-radius**, so an automatic replace is really hard

Comment: yes I have already done that, but in the case  "-moz-border-radius-topleft is translated to border-top-left-radius" is more complicated

Comment: there are 5 possible properties (that I know of) with "-moz-border-radius". couldn't possibly take more than a couple of minutes with a search / replace all, your not changing any of the values only the property name. Would take a lot longer waiting for an answer here than to make the change I would have though

Comment: You are right but actually the solution is to add the 5 new possibilities and not to remove any, for fallback support

Comment: Not directly related to jQuery UI -- I find using _mixin_ in LESS is proved to be helpful in a situation like this. In this case, you'd have a mixin that takes care of the different syntax for e.g. top-left rounded corner property. If there is new syntax in the future, we just need to update the mixin.

Comment: @albanx - that kind of automatic replace doesn't have to be really hard; for example, try this (_using `sed` in a `bash` terminal_): `sed 's/-moz-border-radius-topleft/border-top-left-radius/g' file.css` - and then use `sed`'s `-i` switch for [inplace replacement](http://compdottech.blogspot.com/2009/01/sed-inplace-replacement.html)

Comment: I know it, I just wonder how they removed it, all my graphics sunddely from jquery to menus with squared borders :)

Answer (score 5):

`border-radius` is the standard, so it should have always been included in your css as a fallback as browsers adopted the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Previously I used:

```
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
```

but they stopped working in v13. I switched to:

```
border-radius:10px;
```

and it is working again!

Comment: You don't need to replace - but rather add that line (backwards-compatibility)!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you just should have to do nothing, because the jQuery-UI css files declare the border-radii the correct way.

```
<prefixed>-border-radius:xxx
border-radius:xxx
```

This way you shouldn't even notice the change. So I can't believe that you will miss the round corners without having altered the original stylesheet. Perhaps your problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: Yes but It does not declare in correct way this: -moz-border-radius-topleft, almost at old versions

Comment: @albanx Well, then you are using a version of jqueryUI which is rather old. Just try to upgrade your jqueryUi to a version which supports the new syntax.

Answer (score -2):

**Find and Replace** in complete Project...

Comment: Bad idea, since you lose backwards-compatibility! Normally you just should have declared the radii in the standard way too.