# CSS border-radius and -moz-border-radius

Tags: css

I've inherited a web project that is supposed to work in IE8 (as well as the other browsers but I am not worried about them by comparison). When I run the website in Firefox and check the Error Console it mentions:

"**Warning**: Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. Declaration dropped"

Wherever `-moz-border-radius` appears in the style sheet `border-radius` also appears. For example, these were right next to each other in the style sheet:

```
border-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius:20px;
```

Is there any reason to keep the `-moz-border-radius` styling? Is it better to just remove them?

Comment: Firefox threw the warning

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-moz-border-radius hasn't been necessary in firefox for a long time, so I'd remove it. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius

[-moz-border-radius removed from firefox 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927481/moz-border-radius-removed-from-firefox-13)

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is unnecessary now

Comment: @asimes - its not unnecessary if you are using an old version of firefox

Comment: @ScottSelby hasn't been necessary since Firefox 2. Hopefully no one is still running that...

Comment: yea - i work with non-profits running IE6 , so you never know

Comment: @ScottSelby Yikes, and I thought the IE8 requirement was bad. Hopefully they don't use Firefox 2

Comment: @ScottSelby RE: IE6 - My condolences :)

Comment: Looks like Firefox 13 (removed need for -moz-border-radius) was released on June 5, 2012  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history

Answer (score 2):

`border-radius:20px;` will work in all new browsers

`-moz-border-radius:`  was for older versions of FireFox , and `-webkit-border-radius:` was for older versions of Chrome.   Both browsers update them selves so users *SHOULD* be ok with `border-radius:` for everything .

I don't see wrong though with adding extra properities in CSS that may not be used by new browsers to ensure that all old browsers also function properly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just code cleaning the project right now so if something throws a warning / error I correct it so I figured I'd remove it.