# CSS3 animating border-radius on Firefox not working

Tags: css, firefox, animation

I'm currently trying to make an animated expanding sphere(circle) which is only a div with applied border-radius using css3 only.

I managed to make the animation work on webkit browsers maintaining the sphere/circle shape of the animated element but I have no idea why it doesn't work on firefox. It do have some border-radius applied(about 20px) but doesn't work like how it does on webkit.

Here's the code that I use.

```
@-webkit-keyframes expandSphere
{
    0%{padding:10px; opacity: 0;}
    25%{height: 150px; border-radius: 150px; width:150px; left:520px; top:200px;}
    55%{height: 350px; border-radius: 500px; width:350px; left:420px; top:100px;}
    75%{height: 547px; border-radius: 700px; width:700px; top:0; left:250px;}
    100%{height:547px; opacity: 1; top:0px; left:0; width:1180px; border-radius: 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes expandSphere
{
    0%{padding:10px; height:20px; width:20px; opacity: 0; -moz-border-radius: 50px;}
    25%{height: 150px; width:150px; left:520px; top:200px; -moz-border-radius: 150px;}
    55%{height: 350px; width:350px; left:420px; top:100px; -moz-border-radius: 500px;}
    75%{height: 547px; width:700px; top:0; left:250px; -moz-border-radius: 700px;}
    100%{height:547px; opacity: 1; top:0px; left:0; width:1180px; -moz-border-radius: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to stop using vendor prefixes when not needed.

In particular, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10927566/720912

Comment: Coool man! Thanks! It worked. Now I'm moving on to the opera. And I have no luck in it.

Comment: For Opera, use *unprefixed* keyframe animations. And add them **after** the prefixed ones. Firefox also supports keyframe animations umprefixed. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation